# can't point to the first object of my array

Tags: java, arrays, static

i've this problem, i'm learning java and trying to do one of my exercise i can't point to the first object of my created array.

here the code:

```
    public class prova {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                    int y=0;

                    int n=0;

                    int h=20, g=21,d=56,z=44;

                    int conf=100;

                    riga[] array=new riga[100];

                    array[n]= new riga(3,10,5,6);


                    while(conf !=105) {

                    array[n]= new riga(h++,g++,d++,z++);

                    array[n].nextbet=array[0].importobet;// i want to set the nextbet field of my current array to the importobet value of the first object in this array. Look the output down here.

                    System.out.println("ecco:"+array[n].nextbet);
                    n++;

                    conf++;

                    }
}

class riga {

//variabili

        static public int numerostep;
        static public double importoquota;
        static public double importobet;
        static public boolean esito;
        static public double cassa;
        static public double profitto;
        static public double nextbet;
   //costruttore
        public riga(int a,double d, double c,double f){

                numerostep=a;
                importobet=d;
                importoquota=c;
                cassa=f;


}
  //metodi
        public static void stampaRiga(int a, double b, double c,double f) {

                System.out.println("step:"+a+"***importo:"+b+"***quota:"+c+"***cassa:"+f);
}

}




}
```

i write the problem in the comment near the line where the it is located. In this example case the output is:

```
21.0
22.0
23.0 
........
```

but it should be:

```
21.0
21.0
21.0
........
```

Comment: it would be nice if you put some order to your indention and obey this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367 and please use meaningful variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are incrementing it initiall h=20 n=0

```
array[n]= new riga(h++,g++,d++,z++);

1st iteration n=0 h++ ie 20+1=21  so h will have 21
2nd iteration n=1 h++ ie 21+1=22  so h will have 22
3rd iteration n=2 h++ ie 22+1=23  so h will have 23
```

Comment: change g++ to g+1 you will get the output you want

Comment: it is h not g h++ to h+1

Answer (score 2):

```
array[n]= new riga(h++,g++,d++,z++);
```

you increment `g` with every iteration so the first output is correct